# How to replace items in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I request JSON objects with unique ids through an API. Some of these items already exist in my MongoDB database. Is there some functionality like this:

```
Collection.replace({ id: '12345' }, JSON_object)
```

which looks for an object with that id field in the first place, and then replaces it with the new object, if it finds one, or adds a new object to the collection, if no matching object was found?

I am doing this in node.js with mongoose. Unfortunatly, the ObjectId implementation seems faulty there, so I am searching for a general approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDb core function **update** has **upsert** option:

```
db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi )
```

which will insert **objNew** if there is no document matching **criteria**. Try:

```
db.collection.update( { _id: ObjectID('423523452') }, JSON_object, true )
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29

Answer (score 4):

Remember that you must use the `db.bson_serializer.ObjectID` function in order to get mongodb ids.

```
var ObjectID = db.bson_serializer.ObjectID;
db.collection.update({_id: ObjectID('423523452')}, {foo: 'bar'}, true)
```